# Tabular display of features not working as expected in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have just installed QGIS 2.18 and was dismayed to find that "open attribute table" no longer displays data in a tabular format.  Instead I get list of 'filter' values with a check box and the rest of the pane taken up with the details of the selected value as a form.

I have just looked at the 2.18 Docs and this is clearly not what is meant to happen.

Any hints on how to get back the old behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you may have opened your table in "Form View".  In the lower-right corner of the pane there should be two buttons - One to display in Form View, the other in Table view.  Click the Table View button to display your table.

Form View:
[image]

Table View:
[image]

Comment: You are right,  that appears to be exactly what happened.  The problem is that the controls to switch views are not visible.  I also note that all the windows have two title bars!   I think what has happened is that the second title bar has pushed the controls off the visible part of the window.

Comment: Ah!  resizing the window reveals the missing controls...  problem fixed.  BTW the dual title bars is the same for all windows.   Mac bug?

Comment: @RussellFulton it may be worth asking a separate question about these dual title bars, as it does sound odd. Include a screenshot highlighting the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this asked a few times; it seems to be a common point of confusion (and it trips me up regularly too).

I think this might have happened if you clicked on the "toggle multi edit" icon by mistake...

[image]

The icon is between the "edit" and "save" icons, and looks quite similar to its neighbours, so it's all too easy to click on it by mistake.
You can always use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to save your edits rather than using the mouse, to make this less likely.

Another option is to change the attribute table mode in the settings- it defaults to "remember last setting", so change this to "Table view".

[image]